# Interference between dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

In my view I have a code like

```
<div id="DDLs">
<p>Begin: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, Model.items, new { @id = "list1" })</p>
</div>  
...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list1").change(function () {
        var countrySelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();
        $.get('@Url.Action("MyAction")',
            { id: countrySelected }, function (data) {
                $("#apendedInfo").html(data);
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

That works as expected.The problem is when I add another dropdownlistfor like this:

```
<div id="DDLs">
<p>Begin: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, Model.items, new { @id = "list1" })</p> 
<p>Options: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option, @ViewBag.Options as SelectList, new { @id = "list2"})</p> 
</div>
```

After adding it, change event is sometimes fired with selected value of the added dropdownlist, not the one that I expect it would. I have no idea why.

**Edit:** 
Thanks to dansasu11 answer, I've figuired out that the problem was in line:

```
var countrySelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();
```

I changed it to:

```
var countrySelected = $(this).val();
```

Now everything works - of ocurse insted of reciving Text of selected item I'm getting its value, which is also fine.

Perhaps I should have spent more time learning jQuery.

Comment: Well I'm just a newbie here and I'm not sure if i did right but that answer realy helped me to solve my problem so according to the text that is shown on hover acceptance mark - "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution" - I accepted it. Have i done something wrong?

Comment: Well, I would also accept the answer which helped me but - once the answer is correct. So, accept when dansasu11 makes his answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#list1").change(function () {
    var countrySelected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $.get('@Url.Action("MyAction")',
        { id: countrySelected }, function (data) {
            $("#apendedInfo").html(data);
        });
});
 });
</script>
```

or if you want to be able to select any of the dropdown and get the selected option then change to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
$("select").change(function () {
    var countrySelected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $.get('@Url.Action("MyAction")',
        { id: countrySelected }, function (data) {
            $("#apendedInfo").html(data);
        });
    });
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: The statement should be `$(this).find("option:selected").text();` for the `text` of the selected option - or `$(this).val();` for the `value` as OP explained. So, please edit you answer to prevent other people using non-working solution.